# sscanf returns 1 when searching for float in a string starting with the character n or i

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code I would expect sscanf to return 0, but it returns 1 and assigns 0.000000 to the float variable x.  The same behavior occurs when the string begins with the letter i, but with no other letter.

```
void main() {
    int ss_return;
    float x;
    char str_to_sscanf[] = "noduh";

    ss_return = sscanf( str_to_sscanf, "%f", &x );

    printf( "\n\nThe word passed to sscanf is %s", str_to_sscanf );
    printf( "\n\nWhen looking for a float, sscanf returned %d", ss_return );
    printf( "\n\nand assigned %f to x (declared as float)", x );
    printf( "\n\nWHY DID sscanf NOT RETURN ZERO????" );
}
```

The output of the program is:  "two weird looking characters"duh

What am I missing?

Comment: Works on my machine.  You'll need to document the compiler and C runtime library that you are using.

Comment: Yes, what OS? I suspect this is a bug. *Probably* what's happening is that the buggy `scanf` implementation is seeing the `'n'` as the first character of a potential match (`"nan"`) and then, when it fails to fully match, considering a non-zero-length partial match as "success", then passing it to `strtod` and getting `0.0`.

Comment: Don't use `void main`, use the proper `int main`.

Comment: Specifically `int main(void)` -- and the `#include <stdio.h>` is not optional.

Comment: Windows Vista Home Premium SP2; LCC-win32 compiler.  I was thinking something similar, that the implementation of sscanf was interpreting the leading n as something and the leading i as something and aborting.  Confusing that sscanf returns 1 in that case. I'll try using a different compiler...

Comment: Sorry, I must have not copied the #include <stdio.h> from my program.  I changed to int main( void ) and same behavior, but thanks for the correction.

Comment: What does `strtod("noduh", NULL)` return?

Comment: As a general rule, at least for command-line programs, it works better to include a newline at the end of each print format string rather than (or as well as) at the start.  It has no effect on the (mis)behaviour of `sscanf()` in this context.

Comment: Keith - strtod("noduh", NULL) returns 0.0, which it seems is the return value for strtod when it fails to convert.  For fun I also tried strtod("noduh999.999", NULL) and got 0.0 back.  To make sure strtod was working properly, I tried strtod("999.999", NULL) and got 999.999 back.

Comment: Recompiled the program using Tiny C and sscanf works as it should.  Very strange.  I have e-mailed the developer of lcc-win32 to see if he can explain the behavior of sscanf.  Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your library's state machine is seeing the "n" as the possible start of "NaN" and the "i" as the possible start of "inf" which is letting it fall into the float conversion code.  Then it immediately bails out because it can't finish parsing and assigns a default value.